# new 2tb hd not useable

Tags: hard-drive

I have a new hard drive which I can't seem to access correctly. It is a 2TB lacie drive and when I connect it I only see ~400MB. This is the output from `fdisk`:

[image]

What is wrong and how can I proceed?

Comment: Have you formatted it yet? It's showing as FDisk rather than GUID, so I'm guessing not.

Comment: I have formatted it, hence the Apple HFS section. Why it doesn't see the rest of the disk when I want to erase I have no idea

Comment: Reformat it - as GUID not MBR. It looks like you just partitioned it, not formatted. idk why it doesn't see it, but that would be the first thing to try.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out Disk Utility wasn't showing all devices, only volumes. I changed that option in the menu and was able to actually format the 2TB drive.

[image]